# how can i store latitude and longitude values in different variables for api request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, api

I wanted to store Latitude and Longitude in 2 different variables so that it can be used in another **api request** in `javascript`

```
let weather={   
        key:"your api key",
        getweather(city){
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast? 
                q=${city}&appid=${this.key}&units=metric`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.show(data))
        const encodeurl=encodeURI(fetch);
        },

   show(data){    
        **const{lat,lon}=data.city.coord;**
          console.log(lat,lon);
       }  
  }

 weather.getweather("mumbai");
```

Comment: What does the data that you're trying to manipulate look like?

Comment: its weather data in json format

Comment: Are you sure?  (the syntax would be correct if the data is correct, i.e. set a breakpoint and inspect your data).

Comment: Are you sure `coord` is an object and that it has the `lat` and lon` properties on it?

Comment: yes Nick coord has lat & lon properties in it .

Comment: If coord has lat and lon, then what is the error you're getting..?

Comment: there is no error in the code i want the lat & lon values in different variables to use

Comment: Read the [API document](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON).

Comment: You have them in in different variables. Perhaps you're missing the part of your code that is not working...?